# Text before and after radioButtons

Tags: html, shiny

I'd like to have a single line of text with radio buttons in the middle - essentially, a label before and after the buttons, like:

```
Make a selection from (*) some ( ) most ( ) all available fields
```

I know that the label parameter can put the text inline beforehand, but I'm not sure how to do it after. This, as expected, puts the second part of the text on a new line:

```
tagList(
    shiny::radioButtons(
      ns("field_sel"),
      label = "Make a selection from ",
      choices = c("some", "most", "all"),
      selected = "some",
      inline = TRUE
    ),
    htmltools::HTML(" available fields")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would do for the label. For the text after the radio buttons, you can use `htmltools::tagQuery`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagQuery(radioButtons(
    "field_sel",
    label = "Make a selection from ",
    choices = c("some", "most", "all"),
    selected = "some",
    inline = TRUE
  ))$find(".shiny-options-group")$append(tags$span("available fields"))$allTags()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```